# Does PHP provide request to object mapping

Tags: php, jsp

In JSP there is

```
<jsp:useBean....../>
<jsp:setProperty name="entry" property="*" />
```

(If all of the request parameters match with the bean property names)

Is there something like this in PHP?

I'm a beginner in PHP so pardon me if its a naive question.

Comment: I do not know JSP very well, but PHP does not have Beans. You might want to assign values from the `$_POST` or `$_GET` array to object properties of the same name?

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a framework with a language. There are frameworks in PHP too that do similar stuff, look at the [Zend Framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/zend-framework2/info) for instance.

Do **not** expect the PHP ecosystem to be the java ecosystem though, these are whole different languages with different approaches to problems.